# MassTransit log4net logging with castle log4net logging facility

Tags: log4net, castle-windsor, castle, masstransit

I've a project where I use MassTransit + Castle Windsor + Castle Windsor log4net facility. I'd like to add MassTransit log4net logging, however it seems that those two "logging mechanisms" are incompatible, because castle requires log4net = 1.2.10 and MassTransit requires log4net > 2.0.3. Did anyone have similar problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Castle.Core-log4net1211 that allows to use a log4net version greater than 1.2.10

those are my dependencies

```
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Castle.Core-log4net1211" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Castle.LoggingFacility" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```